# TimeWindowCompactionStrategy How this works . when time counter starts after creation

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I have a Cassandra Table using TWCS with 1 day time window, which means compaction will be done after 1 day window. So, now my query is how will  Cassandra decide when compaction will be done for the very first time-

1) Exactly after 1 day when table was created like I created table at 10:00 am (IST) on 1 April, so compaction will initiate at 10:00 am on 2 April
2) It starts from 00:00 hours that means every day at 00:00 hours , compaction will be initiated.

I need to understand this concept like whenever I make read query on a table tracing logs shows that data comes from multiple SSTables, I need to know why ? My table partition key is SensorID and date. So, as per concept the entire partition key is stored at one node. So, ideally the complete partition should come from single SSTable. I'll share the tracing log to get clarity.

```
Tracing session: 5ddecd60-546a-11e9-83a5-4bbd3b5675f1

 activity                                                                                                                              | timestamp                  | source      | source_elapsed | client
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------------
                                                                                                                    Execute CQL3 query | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.966000 | 192.168.0.2 |              0 | 192.168.0.2
                                                      READ message received from /192.168.0.2 [MessagingService-Incoming-/192.168.0.2] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.915000 | 192.168.0.3 |             74 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                    Executing single-partition query on locationinfohash [ReadStage-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.916000 | 192.168.0.3 |            380 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                                            Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.916000 | 192.168.0.3 |            452 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                    Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 112 [ReadStage-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.916000 | 192.168.0.3 |            588 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                    Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 111 [ReadStage-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.916000 | 192.168.0.3 |            900 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                    Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 110 [ReadStage-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.916000 | 192.168.0.3 |           1177 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                     Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 89 [ReadStage-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.917000 | 192.168.0.3 |           1466 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                                            Key cache hit for sstable 52 [ReadStage-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.917000 | 192.168.0.3 |           1673 | 192.168.0.2
                                               Skipped 0/5 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.917000 | 192.168.0.3 |           1726 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                               Merged data from memtables and 5 sstables [ReadStage-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.922000 | 192.168.0.3 |           6639 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                                Read 100 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.922000 | 192.168.0.3 |           6854 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                                      Enqueuing response to /192.168.0.2 [ReadStage-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.922000 | 192.168.0.3 |           6926 | 192.168.0.2
                                       Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /192.168.0.2 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/192.168.0.2-Small] | 2019-04-01 10:39:01.922000 | 192.168.0.3 |           7181 | 192.168.0.2
                                                      READ message received from /192.168.0.2 [MessagingService-Incoming-/192.168.0.2] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.186000 | 192.168.0.1 |             42 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                    Executing single-partition query on locationinfohash [ReadStage-6] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.187000 | 192.168.0.1 |            824 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                                            Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-6] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.187000 | 192.168.0.1 |            967 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                     Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 68 [ReadStage-6] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.187000 | 192.168.0.1 |           1135 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                     Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 67 [ReadStage-6] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.187001 | 192.168.0.1 |           1437 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                     Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 66 [ReadStage-6] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.188000 | 192.168.0.1 |           1863 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                                            Key cache hit for sstable 45 [ReadStage-6] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.188000 | 192.168.0.1 |           2277 | 192.168.0.2
                                               Skipped 0/4 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-6] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.188000 | 192.168.0.1 |           2354 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                               Merged data from memtables and 4 sstables [ReadStage-6] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.194000 | 192.168.0.1 |           8300 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                                Read 100 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-6] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.195000 | 192.168.0.1 |           8529 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                                      Enqueuing response to /192.168.0.2 [ReadStage-6] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.195000 | 192.168.0.1 |           8599 | 192.168.0.2
                                       Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /192.168.0.2 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/192.168.0.2-Small] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.195000 | 192.168.0.1 |           8908 | 192.168.0.2
 Parsing select * from trackfleet_db.locationinfohash where pkhash = '34AAB6D5F1431151211AF721F951057F'; [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.966000 | 192.168.0.2 |            140 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                                     Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.966000 | 192.168.0.2 |            219 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                          reading data from /192.168.0.1 [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.966000 | 192.168.0.2 |            401 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                  speculating read retry on /192.168.0.3 [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.967000 | 192.168.0.2 |            462 | 192.168.0.2
                                                   Sending READ message to /192.168.0.1 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/192.168.0.1-Small] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.967000 | 192.168.0.2 |            504 | 192.168.0.2
                                                   Sending READ message to /192.168.0.3 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/192.168.0.3-Small] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.967000 | 192.168.0.2 |            558 | 192.168.0.2
                                          REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /192.168.0.3 [MessagingService-Incoming-/192.168.0.3] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.976000 | 192.168.0.2 |           9643 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                       Processing response from /192.168.0.3 [RequestResponseStage-16] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.976000 | 192.168.0.2 |           9700 | 192.168.0.2
                                          REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /192.168.0.1 [MessagingService-Incoming-/192.168.0.1] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.976000 | 192.168.0.2 |          10372 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                       Processing response from /192.168.0.1 [RequestResponseStage-10] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.977000 | 192.168.0.2 |          10447 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                                      Initiating read-repair [RequestResponseStage-10] | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.977000 | 192.168.0.2 |          10479 | 192.168.0.2
                                                                                                                      Request complete | 2019-04-01 10:39:02.976914 | 192.168.0.2 |          10914 | 192.168.0.2
```

Need explanation as why it is reading from SSTable and how TWCS compaction works and how can we tune it ?